# Как не адаптировать каждый пиксель в html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет! Такой вопрос, я натянул сайт на *1440px, 440px и 1920* px, как мне сделать так, чтоб если пользователь зашел на сайт с экраном 1296px(например), то ему показывалась версия 1440px, то есть от 1440px до 768px, показывалось всегда 1440px. У меня есть решение, но оно не такое ак мне нужно

```
@media screen and (max-width:1440px) and (min-width:768px){
    body{
        width:1440px
    }
}
```

Но проблема этого решения в том, что если я захожу,то мне нужно лупой уменьшать сайт, что увидеть его полностью, то есть он обрезается

Вопрос, как сделать, чтоб он не обрезался, а полностью показывался весь?

Comment: `body { width: 100vw }`?

Comment: Body { width: 100%;} пишут всегда. Всегда, это значит всегда. С vw для ширины экрана появляется проблема, когда появляется вертикальный скрол. И, для адаптивной верстки не используются четкие размеры в пикселях

Comment: Первий раз встречаю такое тех задание. В 99% всем нужен адаптивный сайт который перестраивался независимо от разрешения экрана пользователя. Смотрит он сайт с трекер часов или на телевизоре. Очень похоже на намахивание клиента заказа который предоставил 3 разрешения дизайна. Нормального ответа ту не будет, потому что задача - не адекватная. Горизонтальный скролл будет всегда.

Comment: Попробуй убрать метатег<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> так как он говорит браузеру установить ширину веб-страницы равной ширине устройства